# values not showing up in select button

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I am trying to get options in select button but its not showing up.

my code is as below:

index.html:

```
<select ng-model="main.order" ng-options="order as order.title for order in main.orders"></select>
```

app.js:

```
$http.get('src/json/sortingKeys.json').success(function(response){
    vm.orders =  response.orders;
    vm.order = vm.orders[0];
  });
```

Before it was working fine and i was getting values in select options. but then I wanted to use material design from http://materializecss.com/about.html. 
I have also initialized "select" as per what they told :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('select').material_select();});
```

Eventhough I am getting values to html page, I am not getting them inside select options. please refer the below code which i can see after inspecting in browser:

```
    <div class="select-wrapper"><input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true"
                                   data-activates="select-options-082235b8-d9be-505d-90ab-c4cc9b9bb765" value=""
                                   type="text"><i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></i>
  <select  class="selectOptions ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid initialized" ng-model="main.order"
        ng-options="order as order.title for order in main.orders">
  <option selected="selected" label="Year Ascending" value="object:16">Year Ascending</option>
  <option label="Year Descending" value="object:17">Year Descending</option>
  <option label="Title Ascending" value="object:18">Title Ascending</option>
  <option label="Title Ascending" value="object:19">Title Ascending</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Code is available at github: https://github.com/pradeepb6/firstExample/tree/master/app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained how to fix it in [this issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/706#issuecomment-78628345).

Basically you need to create a directive for all select elements, it can be bound to the **select** element, and call `$(element).material_select();` in its link function.

Also, since it won't know when the data that came from the server is done, you'll need to prevent the select from being created at all. a **ngIf** will do the trick. So your select will look like this:

```
<select 
    ng-model="main.order" 
    ng-options="order as order.title for order in main.orders" 
    ng-if="main.orders">
</select>
```

As for the directive, you can use [this one](https://gist.github.com/viniciusmelquiades/66ed8039e3709b126e52). I use this in my code that will soon hit production ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the suggestions suggested by you. please refer the what i did and suggest me if i am missing something.

[link](http://pastebin.com/kbNCNseu)

Comment: @Pradeepb How are you initializing the select? Are you using the directive I posted(link right below my code example)? If it doesn't work, update your Github repository, and if necessary, I'll fork it and make the necessary changes.

Comment: yes. I initialised select using ('select').material_select() as per the guidelines. I have updated the Github repository. Thanks for your time

Comment: I forked your project and fixed the code. I only did one commit, so read it for details/instructions. The code is [here](https://github.com/viniciusmelquiades/firstExample/tree/master/app).


Sorry it took me so long, but I would only have time when I got home.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to always work when you 'dropdown' (pun intended) to use the default browser approach to the select instead of materializing it:

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="student.name">
     <option ng-repeat="item in students" value="{{ item.$id }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>
</select>
```

The take away is the `class="browser-default"` part. See here: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

The styling doesn't look like material, however, you could drop in a couple of lines of CSS to style it up like material, without suffering the missing dynamic rendering capabilities.